# Listing the latest unstable gem version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I do:

```
gem search -r rails
```

It shows me:

```
rails (2.3.8)
```

But how do I know the latest unstable version which is 3.0.0.rc so that I can use it:

```
gem install rails --version=3.0.0.rc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gem search -r rails --pre`.